# Error in running a python script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a simple python program that would control the browser. However when I do the following actions I get an error.

Actions:

I wrote this on my file:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class InstaBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

then I started a virtual environment and typed this in the command line

```
python3 -I insta_bot.py
```

and then

```
bot = InstaBot()
```

However I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'InstaBot' is not defined
```

Comment: what is the name of the file in which you defined InstaBot?

Comment: Try using the `-i` flag.

Comment: -i for interactive shell and -I to isolate the current user's site-directory, pythonpath.. In short use -i instead